# (Xcode) Command phaseScriptExecution failed with a non-zero exit code error (from EMPTY vision OS Unity Project)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, visionos, cocoapods-1.1.1

Unity Version: 2022.3.8f1
XCode Version: XCode 15 beta 5
Targeted Platform: Vision OS

The build succeeded form Unity but when I try to make build from XCode, it shows an error with GameAssembly, Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a non-zero exit code.

I have tried the latest release of XCode that is XCode 15 beta 8 but finds no luck.
I have tried solution with cocoa pods but it did not work as well.

Comment: If you look around, there should be a verbose description of the non-zero failure... if you can find it, can you put it in here?

Comment: As @benc mentioned, having more of the exact error message and the specific portion where things break would be helpful. It's unlikely that people will be able to debug this given this little info. Best of luck! I hope the Unity game is fun :)

Comment: I mentioned this as well, because I noticed that in Xcode 15 (my brain seems operate in Xcode 13 era...) when I had build problems, it was a lot easier to tap on a twistie-display and Xcode would show the full line command that it failed on.

Comment: @MuhObaid: There is a known issue with Unity & Xcode 15. Could this be related: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/building-projects-with-il2cpp-scripting-backend-for-apple-platforms-fails-with-xcode-15-dot-0b6-or-newer

Answer (score 1):

I also had breaking changes with the update to Xcode 15. I tried several different forum solutions, nothing worked.
In the end, I updated to the latest version of Unity (which for me was 2022.3.10f1, from 2022.3.4f1).
Everything is working now!